# How to fill in missing dates for each ID/Group in a specific time interval in a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, date, pyspark

Let's say I have data collected for each person in a 5m interval in which the start and end of the sequences are arbitrary (as they are actions executed by those persons), how do I fill all of the missing dates for each person from the start to end in that specific interval (5m / any other)

example dataset:

| date (d/m/y hh:mm:ss) | did_action | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/2/22 14:54:00 | a | 1 |
| 13/2/22 15:22:00 | b | 1 |
| 15/6/22 12:01:00 | a | 2 |
| 19/6/22 12:15:00 | b | 2 |

example pseudo-output:

| date (d/m/y hh:mm:ss) | did_action | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/2/22 14:54:00 | a | 1 |
| (all 5m periods until last action) | NaN | 1 |
| 13/2/22 15:22:00 | b | 1 |
| 15/6/22 12:01:00 | a | 2 |
| (all 5m periods until last action) | NaN | 2 |
| 19/6/22 12:15:00 | b | 2 |

*notes:*

*1. the (all 5m periods until last action) pseudo-output symbolises that it would be separate rows in the same fashion as the rest.*

*2. the same person_id may have other actions in the middle, not just a start and an end.*

*3. it would be handy to be able to fill the `did_action` column for the generated gap fill with a null/any other arbitrary value*

Comment: `the same person_id may have other actions in the middle, not just a start and an end.` how does the data look like in this case? please add examples in the question -- have and want both.

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 2.4+, one can use the PySpark SQL [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html#pyspark-sql-functions-sequence) function as follows -- No `udf`s required. *(tested on google colaboratory with spark 3.1.3)*

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('next_ts', func.lead('ts').over(wd.partitionBy('person').orderBy('action'))). \
    withColumn('next_ts', 
               func.when(func.col('next_ts').isNull(), func.col('ts')).
               otherwise(func.col('next_ts'))
               ). \
    withColumn('ts_range_arr', func.expr('sequence(ts, next_ts, interval 5 minute)')). \
    withColumn('exploded_ts_range', func.explode('ts_range_arr')). \
    withColumn('action', 
               func.when(func.col('ts') != func.col('exploded_ts_range'), func.lit(None)).
               otherwise(func.col('action'))
               ). \  # this makes the new timestamp rows have null action
    select('exploded_ts_range', 'action', 'person'). \
    show(5)

# +-------------------+------+------+
# |  exploded_ts_range|action|person|
# +-------------------+------+------+
# |2022-02-10 14:54:00|     a|     1|
# |2022-02-10 14:59:00|  null|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:04:00|  null|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:09:00|  null|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:14:00|  null|     1|
# +-------------------+------+------+
```

---

Alternatively, here's a way to do it using `udf`.
Note that I converted the timestamps to default format ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") before using the `udf`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd
import pandas as pd

# create a list of datetimes in 5 minute intervals using pandas `date_range()`
def dateRangeIn5Minutes(start_ts, end_ts):
    if end_ts is not None:
        range_ls = list(pd.date_range(start_ts, end_ts, freq='5T'))
    else:
        range_ls = [pd.to_datetime(start_ts)]
    return range_ls

ts_range_udf = func.udf(dateRangeIn5Minutes, ArrayType(TimestampType()))

# create a column with next action's timestamp and use that as end time
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('next_ts', func.lead('ts').over(wd.partitionBy('person').orderBy('action'))). \
    withColumn('ts_range_arr', ts_range_udf('ts', 'next_ts')). \
    withColumn('exploded_ts_range', func.explode('ts_range_arr')). \
    select('exploded_ts_range', 'action', 'person'). \
    show(5)

# +-------------------+------+------+
# |  exploded_ts_range|action|person|
# +-------------------+------+------+
# |2022-02-10 14:54:00|     a|     1|
# |2022-02-10 14:59:00|     a|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:04:00|     a|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:09:00|     a|     1|
# |2022-02-10 15:14:00|     a|     1|
# +-------------------+------+------+
```

Action "b" for person "1" will only have 1 record as there is no next action.

```python
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('next_ts', func.lead('ts').over(wd.partitionBy('person').orderBy('action'))). \
    withColumn('ts_range_arr', ts_range_udf('ts', 'next_ts')). \
    withColumn('exploded_ts_range', func.explode('ts_range_arr')). \
    select('exploded_ts_range', 'action', 'person'). \
    filter(func.col('action') == 'b'). \
    show(5)

# +-------------------+------+------+
# |  exploded_ts_range|action|person|
# +-------------------+------+------+
# |2022-02-13 15:22:00|     b|     1|
# +-------------------+------+------+
```

---

Comment: Note - `data_sdf` is filtered for `person = '1'`. Also, you can choose to use the timestamp in the `orderBy()` instead of `action`

Comment: Why not use spark [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html) function instead of UDF?

Comment: @blackbishop thanks for the note. I was unaware of the function -- been using spark 2.x before it was introduced. It'd be beneficial to post an answer with the same.

Comment: @blackbishop 

I get this error AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'sequence(ts, next_ts, INTERVAL '05' MINUTE)' due to data type mismatch: 
sequence uses the wrong parameter type. The parameter type must conform to:
1. The start and stop expressions must resolve to the same type.
2. If start and stop expressions resolve to the 'date' or 'timestamp' type
then the step expression must resolve to the 'interval' or
'interval year to month' or 'interval day to second' type,
otherwise to the same type as the start and stop expressions.

Comment: @laurentivs how are you using it? can you share the statement here? also, are the `ts` `next_ts` columns of timestamp type?

Comment: Nevermind @samkart it was a silly error with the dtype of the time column. It works almost perfectly! the only problem I'm encountering is that it duplicates the previous value of the `action` column (or multiple columns as I have more than 1 one on the real dataset) is there a way to make these *NULL* or fill them with an arbitrary value such as *0*?

Comment: yes, we could use `when()` to make it `null` or any arbitrary value. It'll come before the `select()` -- when `ts` is not eq `exploded_ts_range` then null else `action` -- I'll add that in the answer as well

Comment: Another issue I'm just noticing is that if the next measurement is not exactly 5m away it will try to fill it regardless. For example:

measurement A at 04:22:31
FILLED MEASUREMENT at 4:22:31
measurement B at 04:27:34

this results in duplicated entries for the same period when the time difference is of 4 seconds, is there any way to fix this? 

This happens because there are measurements in the middle, not just start and end, maybe the code is not accounting for this.

Comment: please add these nuances in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245950/discussion-between-laurentivs-and-samkart).