# Pyspark sequence equivalent in spark 2.3

Tags: pyspark, sequence

I am able to generate a time series of date column that occurs between 2 dates using sequence function(available from spark 2.4)
My production system has spark 2.3. How can I achieve same thing using spark 2.3
Below is the code snippet using sequence function.

```
data1 = [
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-01-01", 1),
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-02-01", 1),
    (1, "2022-09-11", "2023-01-01", 2),
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-01-01", 2),
    (1, "2022-09-21", "2023-01-01", 1),
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data1, ["item", "start_d", "activation_d", "dept_id"]
)
df1 = df1.withColumn(
    "week_start",
    SF.explode(SF.expr("sequence(start_d, activation_d, interval 7 day)")),
)
```

How do the same thing without using sequence function.

Comment: you can use UDFs, as the sequence function is only available starting spark 2.4. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72770359/8279585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the same thing using udf function. Here is the udf function and its use for reference

```
def generate_dates(start_date, end_date, interval):
    dates = []
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        dates.append(current_date)
        current_date += timedelta(days=interval)
    return dates

spark.udf.register("generate_dates", generate_dates, ArrayType(DateType()))

data1 = [
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-01-01", 1),
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-02-01", 1),
    (1, "2022-09-11", "2023-01-01", 2),
    (1, "2022-09-01", "2023-01-01", 2),
    (1, "2022-09-21", "2023-01-01", 1),
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data1, ["item", "start_d", "activation_d", "dept_id"]
)

df1 = df1.withColumn(
    "week_start",
    SF.explode(SF.expr("generate_dates(start_date, activation_date, 7)")),
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).